# Detect black circles(not just pixels) in a image using JUI

Tags: java, imaging

I have a image with blackened circles.

The image is a scanned copy of an survey sheet pretty much like an OMR questionnaire sheet.

I want to detect the circles that have been blackened using the `JUI`(if any other api required)

I have a few examples while searching, but they dont give me accurate result.

I tried..*UDAI,Moodle*...etc...

Then I decided to make my own. I am able to detect the black pixels but as follows.

```
BufferedImage mapa = BMPDecoder.read(new File("testjui.bmp"));

             final int xmin = mapa.getMinX();
             final int ymin = mapa.getMinY();

             final int ymax = ymin + mapa.getHeight();
             final int xmax = xmin + mapa.getWidth();


             for (int i = xmin;i<xmax;i++)
             {
                for (int j = ymin;j<ymax;j++)
                {

                 int pixel = mapa.getRGB(i, j);

                 if ((pixel & 0x00FFFFFF) == 0)
                 {
                     System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");
                 }
                }
             }
```

This gives me the co-ordinates of all the black pixels but i cannot make out if its a circle or not.

How can I identify if its a circle.

**2]** Also I want to know if the image scanned is tilted....I know that the Udai api takes care of that, but for some reason I am not able to get my survey template to run with that code.

Answer (score 4):

So if I understood correctly, you have code that picks out the black pixels so now you have the coordinates of all black pixels and you want to determine all of those that fall on a circle.

The way I would approach this is in 2 steps.

1) Cluster the pixels. Create a class called Cluster, that contains a list of points and use your clustering algorithm to put all the points in the right cluster.

2) Determine which clusters are circles. To do this find the midpoint of all of the points in each cluster (just take the mean of all the points). Then find the minimum and maximum distances from the center, The difference between these should be less than the maximum thickness for a circle in your file. These will give you the radii for the innermost and outermost circles contained within the circle. Now use the equation of a circle x^2 + y^2 = radius, with the radius set to a value between the maximum and minimum found previously to find the points that your cluster should contain. If your cluster contains these it is a circle.

Of course other considerations to consider is whether the shapes you have approximate ellipses rather than circles, in which case you should use the equation of an ellipse. Furthermore, if your file contains circle-like shapes you will need to write additional code to exclude these. On the other hand if all of your circles are exactly the same size you can cut the work that needs to be done by having your algorithm search for circles of that size only.

I hope I could be of some help, good luck!

Comment: I think this approach should work for me... But can you suggest me a clustering algorithm in java that would aid this..

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no algorithm that does what you need in Java. What I would do is write an algorithm myself, which would be a variation of k-means algorithm. Essentially you need to write a method for your cluster class called distanceFromCluster(Point p) which loop through each point q in the cluster and calcualte the distance from p to q. This method will allow you to determine whether the point q is close enough to the cluster and if so it should be added to it...

Comment: Then this procedure should be contained in a while loop and terminated when all points are in the correct cluster - i.e. when no points are being moved to new clusters anymore in each pass.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, I created a class that checks weather an image contains a single non black filled black outlined circle.
This class is experimental, it does not provide exact results all the time, feel free to edit it and to correct the bugs you might encounter.
The setters do not check for nulls or out of range values.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 * Checks weather an image contains a single non black filled black outlined circle<br />
 * This class is experimental, it does not provide exact results all the time, feel free to edit it and to correct
 * the bugs you might encounter.
 * @author      Ahmed KRAIEM
 * @version     0.9 alpha
 * @since       2013-04-03
 */
public class CircleChecker {

    private BufferedImage image;

    /**
     * Points that are equal to the calculated radius±<code>radiusesErrorMargin%</code> are not considered rogue points.<br />
     * <code>radiusesErrorMargin</code> must be <code>>0 && <1</code>
     */
    private double radiusesErrorMargin = 0.2;

    /**
     * A shape that has fewer than roguePointSensitivity% of rogue points is considered a circle.<br />
     * <code>roguePointSensitivity</code> must be <code>>0 && <1</code>
     */
    private double roguePointSensitivity = 0.05;
    /**
     * The presumed circle is divided into <code>angleCompartimentPrecision</code> parts,<br />
     * each part must have <code>minPointsPerCompartiment</code> points
     * <code>angleCompartimentPrecision</code> must be <code>> 0</code>
     */
    private int angleCompartimentPrecision = 50;
    /**
     * The minimum number of points requiered to declare a part valid.<br />
     * <code>minPointsPerCompartiment</code> must be <code>> 0</code>
     */
    private int minPointsPerCompartiment = 20;


    public CircleChecker(BufferedImage image) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
    }

    public CircleChecker(BufferedImage image, double radiusesErrorMargin,
            int minPointsPerCompartiment, double roguePointSensitivity,
            int angleCompartimentPrecision) {
        this(image);
        this.radiusesErrorMargin = radiusesErrorMargin;
        this.minPointsPerCompartiment = minPointsPerCompartiment;
        this.roguePointSensitivity = roguePointSensitivity;
        this.angleCompartimentPrecision = angleCompartimentPrecision;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public double getRadiusesErrorMargin() {
        return radiusesErrorMargin;
    }

    public void setRadiusesErrorMargin(double radiusesErrorMargin) {
        this.radiusesErrorMargin = radiusesErrorMargin;
    }

    public double getMinPointsPerCompartiment() {
        return minPointsPerCompartiment;
    }

    public void setMinPointsPerCompartiment(int minPointsPerCompartiment) {
        this.minPointsPerCompartiment = minPointsPerCompartiment;
    }

    public double getRoguePointSensitivity() {
        return roguePointSensitivity;
    }

    public void setRoguePointSensitivity(double roguePointSensitivity) {
        this.roguePointSensitivity = roguePointSensitivity;
    }

    public int getAngleCompartimentPrecision() {
        return angleCompartimentPrecision;
    }

    public void setAngleCompartimentPrecision(int angleCompartimentPrecision) {
        this.angleCompartimentPrecision = angleCompartimentPrecision;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return true if the image contains no more than <code>roguePointSensitivity%</code> rogue points
     * and all the parts contain at least <code>minPointsPerCompartiment</code> points.
     */
    public boolean isCircle() {
        List<Point> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final int xmin = image.getMinX();
        final int ymin = image.getMinY();

        final int ymax = ymin + image.getHeight();
        final int xmax = xmin + image.getWidth();

        for (int i = xmin; i < xmax; i++) {
            for (int j = ymin; j < ymax; j++) {

                int pixel = image.getRGB(i, j);

                if ((pixel & 0x00FFFFFF) == 0) {
                    list.add(new Point(i, j));
                }
            }
        }
        if (list.size() == 0)
            return false;
        double diameter = -1;
        Point p1 = list.get(0);
        Point across = null;
        for (Point p2 : list) {
            double d = distance(p1, p2);
            if (d > diameter) {
                diameter = d;
                across = p2;
            }
        }
        double radius = diameter / 2;
        Point center = center(p1, across);
        int diffs = 0;

        int diffsUntilError = (int) (list.size() * roguePointSensitivity);
        double minRadius = radius - radius * radiusesErrorMargin;
        double maxRadius = radius + radius * radiusesErrorMargin;

        int[] compartiments = new int[angleCompartimentPrecision];


        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            Point p = list.get(i);
             double calRadius = distance(p, center);
             if (calRadius>maxRadius || calRadius < minRadius)
                 diffs++;
             else{
                 //Angle
                 double angle = Math.atan2(p.y -center.y,p.x-center.x);
                 //angle is between -pi and pi
                 int index = (int) ((angle + Math.PI)/(Math.PI * 2 / angleCompartimentPrecision));
                 compartiments[index]++;
             }
             if (diffs >= diffsUntilError){
                 return false;
             }
        }
        int sumCompartiments = list.size() - diffs;
        for(int comp : compartiments){
            if (comp < minPointsPerCompartiment){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private double distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
    }

    private Point center(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return new Point((p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.bmp"));

        CircleChecker cc = new CircleChecker(image);

        System.out.println(cc.isCircle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to program in a template of what a circle would look like, and then make it scalable to suit the different circle sizes.

For example circle of radius 3 would be:

```
  o
 ooo
  o
```

This assumes you have a finite set of circles you need to find, maybe up to 5x5 or 6x6 this would be feasible.

or you could use: [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)
This would involve finding all black pixel groups and then selecting the middle pixel for each one.
Apply this algorithm using the outer pixels as a guid to how big the circle could be.
Finding the difference between black /expected black pixels.
If the black to expected black ratio is high enough, its a black circle and you can delete / whiten it.